# DoCmd Transfer Spreadsheet not working in Windows 10

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a module that works in an Access DB I created before I upgraded to Windows 10. The export is exactly the same, but it doesn't work in Windows 10. I'm relatively new to VBA, so please go easy on me.

I copied the database that works and updated the table names, and it still won't export.

Everything works great except for the export:

```
Public Sub DmwExport()
Application.SysCmd acSysCmdSetStatus, "Exporting Files"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "TABLE NAME", "FILE LOCATION " & Format(Date - Weekday(Date), "mm-dd-yy") & ".xlsx", True
End Sub
```

The DB acts like it's exporting the files and takes approximately 30 seconds, but when I go to the file location, the files aren't there. I've tried on a network shared drive and on my PC's local drive with zero results. I have compiled the DB with no errors, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. All my references are checked also with the 15.0 version. The above code works no problem with a previously created database, but in this one it won't go. I'm at my wits' end. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Added to this post. There is a reference file and driver that need(s) to be added into the new Windows10 versions of local MS Access apps. Just can't pinpoint exact MSI OCX or DLL names needed (Can be searched in Microsoft download site.) Your export issue on TransferSpreadsheet happens on IMPORT function as well:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "targettable", "outsidesourceXLSfileobject", True, "XLS worksheetRange"
```